# Calling A Java Library From A Webpage

Tags: java, html, web, applet, server-side

Currently I have an applet which is used to process an input (a url provided by the user) but since this is the only interaction with the user I would rather not force them to download the entire app. Preferably I want no extra downloading at all.

Is it possible to have let the user enter a url into an html form and then send that input to be processed server-side and then the output is sent back to the user?

I have considered making a tiny applet which takes the url as an input and then calls a server-side library to process it. Still not my ideal solution. Would this actually work?

What I really want it a jar to be called when the user enters form data. Please help

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have let the user enter a url into an html form and
>   then send that input to be processed server-side and then the output
>   is sent back to the user?

Yes absolutely. Use JavaScript in the browser to send this to a Java back-end. This is how something like this is normally done, not via an Applet.